# How can I improve web accessibility for iframes embedding third-party content (specifically images)?

Tags: html, iframe, accessibility, wai-aria, wcag

[I have a web page](https://www.kabeech.com/fun/star-crossed/) that includes an iframe embedding content from [WikiSky](http://www.wikisky.org/).

The content from WikiSky largely consists of a bunch of images stitched together into a map of the sky. None of these images have alternate text, ARIA labels, or titles. This makes the content less accessible per [WCAG SC 1.1.1](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Techniques/failures/F65.html).

As the owner/maintainer of the website the iframe appears on, accessibility of my page to my users is important to me. However, I am not the owner/maintainer of WikiSky and as such I don't have the ability to just add alt tags to the source content.

Is there a way to make the third-party content in my iframe more accessible?

I naïvely tried using JavaScript to add alt tags to the images in the iframe. That didn't work (obviously) because using JavaScript to modify the contents of an iframe introduces security risks.

I also looked for solutions involving the iframe element itself. I thought there might be an attribute that could tell screen readers that the content within the iframe has non-accessible images and give an alternate description for the whole iframe, but I have not found such a solution. I do have aria-label and title attributes set on the iframe, but it doesn't seem to completely resolve the issue.

Alternate question: is this even an issue? Running [axe](https://www.deque.com/axe/) on the page raises an issue for each image within the iframe, but my screen reader (Orca) just skips the iframe element entirely.

Comment: You could try using one or more of their APIs ~ http://www.wikisky.org/api?locale=EN. Then you would be in control of the display contents

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Phil! I'm using the  [Sky Window API](http://www.wikisky.org/skywindow_demo.jsp). That page only shows examples that use iframes. Is there a way to use the API without iframes? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Ah, my apologies. I've never used these services and assumed something called an _API_ would actually be an API. Seems the XML API is the only actual one

Comment: @Phil All good! I know, right? The entire WikiSky platform seems pretty... idiosyncratic. But it seems to be the best service out there for my use case =) Thanks for the response!

Comment: Just spit-balling now but if you really want to control the content, you may need a proxy that can retrieve the original and modify the markup before including it in your own site

Comment: @Phil Hmmm... That sounds attractive. I have little knowledge of setting up such a proxy. Do you know of any resources where I can learn more? Additionally, would this practice be frowned upon due to security implications of changing (potentially misrepresenting) the content of a third-party site within an iframe?

Comment: Actually, I think I may understand what you mean. I could set up my own server, download the html from Sky Window, and then edit and re-serve the content back to my web page. Is that the basic idea? I still have the same concern about the security implications of this solution, and am also wondering about the legal implications (presuming the original content is copyrighted).

Comment: That's correct. It's probably a little too broad a question for Stack Overflow though I'm interested to see if you get any answers around potential attributes for the iframe

Comment: Gotcha gotcha. Me too! Thanks for the help @Phil!

Comment: Just to be clear: There’s a difference between meeting technical WCAG criteria, and rendering your web service accessible. Providing alternative texts for map tiles does not make them accessible. Best would probably be to provide an `aria-description` with an accessibility warning on the `<iframe>`. Even better: think about a comparable service experience for screen reader users.